# How to add extra threads for an I/O Completion Port

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock, io-completion-ports

I am setting up a server according to Winsock IO Completion Port. I am a little uncertain about what's happening in the background and hope I can get some help here.

When I call GetQueuedCompletionStatus() it blocks until a "background task" is completed. Given that it's eventually unblocked and continues, my understanding is that a thread in the background must have handled the task while the main program was blocked.

Given that I haven't created threads manually (CreateThread), I wonder if this happens automatically when I call CreateIoCompletionPort()

Comment: Your application gets a default Thread Pool, have a read of - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports

Comment: @RichardCritten 
Thanks for your reply. Are you referring to the last parameter in CreateIoCompletionPort()?

Comment: I have read through the documents and must admit that it is very unclear and could have been much more simplified.

I understand that you get a pre allocated threadpool but not when it is created. Is it created when I call CreateIoCompletionPort? And how do I monitor/keep track of quantity active/waiting threads? Best regards Arre

Comment: if you create IOCP by self - you need create and manage thread which will be wait on it by self too. `CreateIoCompletionPort` not create any threads of course. and for use system thread pool - you need not create iocp by self but use `BindIoCompletionCallback ` (for old style pool) or `CreateThreadpoolIo` (for new)

Comment: `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` it blocks until a packet will be queued to iocp. *my understanding is that a thread in the background must have handled the task while the main program was blocked.* - wrong

Comment: @RbMm Can you explain why its wrong? If my program is blocked at GetQueuedCompletionStatus and then unblocked when message received,  "something" was going on at the same time in the background

Comment: your program not blocked. thread can wait on iocp and so what ? if you by self wait on iocp - you by self select which and how many threads do this. and nothing in background

Comment: @RichardCritten "Your application gets a default Thread Pool" Does this means that when I CreateIoCompletionPort the system creates its own threadpool to handle the overlapping requests (on sockets/files associated with that port) that my application make?

Comment: @Arre - no, this is mistake. if you create iocp by self - you need handle it by self. create thread for this by self, call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` by self. any system thread pools here unrelated at all